# Sculpture on a mesh with textures

Tags: texturing, sculpting, multiresolution

I'm new to sculpting in Blender. I've modeled a sofa, which I've UV unwrapped and textured with image textures (PBR). Is it okay now if I add a multiresolution and sculpt on the sofa (wrinkles) without ruining my texturing in the process?

Comment: Hello, duplicate your object to make sure that you won't loose the original version. What do you plan to do with the Multires? If you want to bake the details you'll go back to the original anyway. If you want to apply the Multires it will keep the unwrap correct, even though it's better to keep an object as low-poly as possible.

Comment: Thank you! I wont be baking. Just rendering out images. Multires is just for more geometry to sculpt on. How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "how should I proceed"? You just need to click on the Subdivide button and increase the Level Viewport and Sculpt, but of course the additional topology is virtual, so the UVs will stay low-poly. For more geometry you can also use a Subdivision Surface modifier and apply it. Again make sure that you've saved the low-poly version.

Comment: So I wont need multiresolution when sculpting? Just keep my subdivision?

Comment: You can either use the Multires or the Subdivision Surface modifier, if you plan to apply the Multires, then you could choose Subdivision Surface instead

Comment: Which one will not ruin my texturing in the process? Or Im missunderstanding something

Comment: I'm not sure you have any reason to use Multires, against Subdivision Surface, so keep a copy of the current low-poly version of your object, duplicate, apply a Subdivision Surface, sculpt, it should not affect the texture

Comment: Thank you so much!